# Recover an integer matrix from its complex diagonalization

Tags: linear-algebra, modules

Suppose that $A$ is an $n \times n$ integer matrix, and that we have no knowledge of its entries. However, we do know that it is diagonalizable over $\mathbb C$ - in fact, we have the diagonalization (in my case, I am able to obtain this diagonalization because $A$ is of finite order, and I know the characters of its powers). How can we obtain a matrix similar over $\mathbb Z$ to $A$?

Comment: You can just use the [rational canonical from](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frobenius_normal_form)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write the characteristic polynomial of $A$ in the form $p(x) = p_1(x) p_2(x) \cdots p_k(x)$, where each polynomial $p_j$ has non-repeating roots and integer coefficients. Then because your $A$ is diagonalizable, $A$ is similar (over $\Bbb Z$) to the block-diagonal matrix
$$
\pmatrix{C(p_1) \\ & \ddots \\ && C(p_k)},
$$
where $C(p)$ is the [companion matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_matrix) associated with $p$.

Comment: The $p_i$ must have simple roots (for example, choose them irreducible).

Comment: @loupblanc of course, forgot to mention that somehow